# Create shareable python dashboard from Jupyter Notebook

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, dashboard

I am using Python via Jupyter Notebook for my analytical works. I want to create an interactive dashboard within Jupyter Notebook and be able to share it with my Managers who do not use Python.
My data is consistently updating so the dashboard should update accordingly.
A workaround for this would be really helpful!

Comment: [Voila](https://voila.readthedocs.io/en/stable/) is the main Jupyter system offering in this vein. [Gallery of examples](https://voila-gallery.org/). For running it inside a browser from static hosted sites using web assembly, see [here](https://twitter.com/psychemedia/status/1633536227889561601) and [here](https://github.com/voila-dashboards/voici). There's also [appmode](https://github.com/oschuett/appmode), and others such as Mercury, see [here](https://towardsdatascience.com/interactive-dashboard-from-jupyter-notebook-with-mercury-framework-e1269fdbe73c).

Comment: Did you search this first? Please read [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), especially the 'Search, and research' section, and follow that guide in the future.